# Google Apps Script Time from Datetime number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet with datetime numbers in the following format:
42,385.744166666700

I am writing a script and I want to extract the time from these numbers in the format HH:MM. The above number should return 17:51.

I tried this code but does not work:

```
function extractMicrosTime(DateTimeNumber) {
  var DateNumber = new Date(DateTimeNumber);
  var hours = DateNumber.getHours();
  var minutes = DateNumber.getMinutes();

  return hours + ":" + minutes;

}
```

Comment: Seems like your original time stamp is a non-standard format. If you try something like 1455223628640 then your function works. What's generating this datetime stamp?

Comment: It is from an Excel sheet originally, formatted as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM. However unformatted it is a large decimal number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will work if you format the source cell as Date time.

[image: format date time]

If you do use it raw it returns 19:0

[A working example is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v9hbuqWTOj5RmluGCf5au5tu4xVRg9P1-ifHa3LMFew/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thanks, that works. Even though it appeared to be formatted it wasn't formatted in Google sheets.

Answer (score 1):

For info, this can be done with script as well. Example below for column A

```
function formatColumn() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col = sh.getRange('A1:A');
  col.setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
}
```